# Trouble getting a custom attribute from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, attributes

I'm trying to write a directive that sets a default date to certain datePicker.

As long as i wrote my situation is the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" telme="insSupplies[$index].start_date" ng-model="insSupplies[$index].start_date" beat-date>
```

As you can see, i have some html with the `telme` custom attribute, which contains the defult Date that must be visible in datePicker

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('beatDate', function (DISPATCHER_BROADCAST) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: "ngModel",
          link : function(scope, elem, attrs,ngModelCtrl) {
              scope.$on(DISPATCHER_BROADCAST.beatStuffLoaded,
                function(){ 
                  var parent = $(elem).parent();
                  var something = scope.$eval(attrs.telme);
                    var dtp = parent.datetimepicker({
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss",
                        showTodayButton: false,
                        defaultDate: something.toDate()
                    });
                    dtp.on("dp.change", function (e) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
              );        
          }
        };
      })
```

The problem here is that i'm not able to access the attr `telme` in any way.

Any hint?

Comment: What happens if you try to access to `telme` but out of the `scope.$on(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a "console.log(attrs)" so you can see which attributes really have your element?

Comment: Ok, let's do one thing. Try to store "attrs" into some variable just before your "$scope.on" line ("var myAttributes = attrs" for example). And then do "console.log" of "myAttributes". I think that when "beatStuffLoaded" event is fired you are loosing the value of "attrs" so storing it should do the trick.